# Was ist das alte Wort für Cousine?

Tags: single-word-request, synonym

Es gibt ja Cousine und Cousin. Für Cousin gibt es aber auch ein veraltetes Wort – *Vetter*. Es findet sich ja noch heute beispielsweise in Vetternwirtschaft. Gibt es da auch eine weibliche Form, oder gab es früher nur das männliche Wort? Wie lautet die ältere Form, wenn sie existiert?

Comment: Ist Vetter wirklich veraltet?

Comment: @Martin Peters: Veraltend, würde ich sagen; aber weniger veraltet als Base (und das weniger veraltet als Muhme). :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Das weibliche Gegenstück ist *Base*. Es wird gelegentlich noch verwendet, aber *Kusine* (oder *Cousine*, in der ursprünglichen französischen Schreibung) ist heute der übliche Ausdruck.

Comment: Danke. Ich habe realisiert, dass Base nicht ideal ist um danach in Google zu suchen, aber wiktionary stimmt Dir zu: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Base

Comment: Es heißt "ich habe erkannt/festgestellt" nicht "realisiert", da "realisiert" = "verwirklicht".

Comment: @falkb; Klar ist das das eingedeutschte "realize" - inzwischen nennt aber auch der Duden unter Punkt 2 *erkennen*, *einsehen*, *begreifen* .genannt.

Comment: Ich warte auf den Tag, an dem der erste Deutsche sagt "Ich kann das nicht stehen" anstelle von "Ich kann das nicht aushalten", wegen "to stand" = "aushalten". :-/

Comment: @falkb *Ich realisiere erst jetzt den vollen Umfang* - durchaus gebräuchlich imho.

Comment: Heißt IMHO "ich erstelle erst jetzt den vollen Umfang". Nur mit dem Wissen über das vergewaltigte Englisch kommt im zweiten Schritt der Aha-Effekt. Aber eigentlich nicht das Thema hier. Sorry und erledigt.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt nicht nur **eine** ältere Vokabel, sondern auch *Muhme*, siehe [Wortschatz Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=45395879), dessen Bedeutung etwas unschärfer ist.

Grimm schreibt dazu:

> daher zunächst [...], der mutter schwester, vgl. unter base th. 1, 1147; aber wenigstens seit den späteren mhd. zeiten hat das wort seinen sinn auch auf die schwester des vaters, geschwisterkinder und weibliche seitenverwandte überhaupt ausgedehnt.

Der Brockhaus von 1894/1896 hat diesen Artikel:
[image: Geschwisterkinder]

Comment: Interessanterweise scheint *Muhme* sowohl *Cousine* also auch *Tante* zu bedeuten, bevorzugterweise aber letzteres.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Stimmt. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Muhme) gibt als Mhd. Ursprung/Bedeutung "Schwester der Mutter" an.

Comment: Es scheint mir sogar (basierend auf dem verlinkten Eintrag beim Wortschatz-Portal und dem Duden-Eintrag) **nur** *Tante* zu bedeuten. Daß *Base* als mögliches Synonym angegeben ist, liegt daran, daß *Base* auch *Tante* bedeuten konnte.

Comment: Wiktionary stimmt chirlu zu, Muhme wird dort als Tante/Schwester der Mutter identifiziert, während Base neben der Bedeutung als Cousine  eine noch ältere Bedeutung als Schwester des Vaters hat. Wieso der Brockhaus das als Synonym zu Cousine sieht ist mir unklar. http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Base http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Muhme

Comment: +1 für die schöne Quelle.

Comment: Wer _Muhme_ nennt, darf dann aber _Oheim_ nicht vergessen ...